# How does cratedb handle updates to the path.data?

Tags: cratedb

Specifically, regarding the pseudo-RAID0 setup:

```
path.data: /path/to/data1,/path/to/data2
```

- How does cratedb handle it if i add more paths to an existing node?

  - Will it work?
  - Will it rebalance the data or only balance as new data arrives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can add more paths anytime.
- the existing shards won't be reshuffeled. rebalancing only happens between the nodes. you can read more about the thresholds here: https://crate.io/docs/reference/configuration.html#routing-allocation